# python - How can I separate a single object file into multiple iterator

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

There is a large file called `/tmp/largefile`, and I want to handle the file line by line. My idea is as follow:

```
                                       |---- Process-001 (largefile-part1)
                                       |
                                       |---- Process-002 (largefile-part2)
(largeefile) --> multiprocessing ----> |
                                       |---- Process-003 (largefile-part3)
                                       |
                                       |---- Process-004 (largefile-part4)
```

`Process-00x` will handle a special part of largefile with `demo` function. `demo` is the process  task function.

```
                                                   |-- [gevent worker001]
                                                   |
demo (Process func) ----> a part of largefile ---->|-- [gevent worker002]
                                                   |
                                                   |-- [gevent ....]
```

How to split a single object file into multiple iterator by process number?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import multiprocessing


def worker(data):
    print(data.strip())
    return data


def demo(itertor):
    '''Parallel programming: Just demo here'''
    for _ in itertor:
        worker(_)
    return itertor


processes = []


f = open("/tmp/largefile")

for i in range(5):
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=demo, args=(f, ))
    processes.append(proc)

for process in processes:
    process.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

Comment: I think you have missed some words out of your question. Could you restate your question more clearly please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `itertools.tee` to return 2 copies of an iterator

```
f = open("/tmp/largefile")

for i in range(5):
    f,f_copy = itertools.tee(f)
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=demo, args=(f_copy, ))
    processes.append(proc)
```

I guess ... this probably isnt really what you want ... but its what your question asks for

Comment: Is there a way to read file line by line ? `multiprocessing` may break a line into serval parts.